# Jsoup display all text() at the line

Tags: java, xml, jsoup

My original xml file is:

```
   </Toto>
      <Ride>5</Ride>
   </Toto>
   <Document>
      <a>
         <b>1234</b>
         <c>foo</c>
         <d>bar</d>
      </a>
   <Document>
```

I want change `1234` by `5678`.

```
File f = new File(filePath);
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new FileInputStream(f), "UTF-8", f.getAbsolutePath(), Parser.xmlParser());
Element elem = doc.select("Document > a > b").first();
TextNode tn = elem.textNodes().get(0);
tn.replaceWith(new TextNode("5478"));
value = doc.toString();
```

My output is xlm file is:

```
   </Toto>
      <Ride>
       5
      </Ride>
   </Toto>
   <Document>
      <a>
         <b>
          5478
         </b>
         <c>
          foo
         </c>
         <d>
          bar
         </d>
      </a>
   <Document>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following statement before toString()

> doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);

I've also found pretty much same problem [How to convert Jsoup Document in a String without put spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088347/how-to-convert-jsoup-document-in-a-string-without-put-spaces)